# What exactly is returned from PCA in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, pca

```
I = double(image1Cropped);
X = reshape(I,size(I,1)*size(I,2),3 );
coeff1 = pca(X);
```

What exactly is happening in the above 3 lines of code?
Why covert an image into double before passing into reshape?
What is the purpose of reshape?
What is returned from `pca(X)`?
Could I use `coeff1` to compare images (for example, comparing faces)?

Comment: Some more info : http://www.numerical-tours.com/matlab/multidim_1_color/#34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PCA, the principal conponents are returned. Of course.

Check the documentation or any online course to understand what a PCA is.

As PCA is a mathematical tool, it needs floating point data to work, that's why there is a `double` in the first line, it is converting the data (most likely `uint8`) into floating point data.

`reshape` is reshaping your image to a huge matrix of  `size(I,1)*size(I,2),3`, so every `X(ii,:)` will be 3 of length.

My guess here is that the image is a RGB image, and that this code tries to get the "principal colours" of the image. What the code does is transform you data to points of 3 values, Red, Green and Blue (as opposed to the normal XYZ) and then getting the principal components of the image. The principal components will be "the principal 3 Colors (conbinations of RGB)" that are in the image.

If you search "PCA of an RGB image" on Google you will find lots of information of how/why to do this.